# For $m,n>0$, $\exists u,v$ with $-n/2\leq v\leq n/2, m=un+v$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

By Euclids's Algorithm, $\exists q,r, m=qn+r, 0\leq r<n$.

If $0\leq r<n, u=q, v=r$.

If $n/2<r<n, u=q+1, v=r-n$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.... it is correct.  There's nothing special about the interval $[0,n-1]$.  $[1,n]$ or $[-5,n-6]$ or  $[516,515+n]$ work just as well.

Comment: Yes, except for the error (which seems to be a typo) as noted in the accepted A. You could also let $u'=m/n\in \Bbb Q$ and let $u''$ be the unique integer such that $u''\le u'<u''+1,$ and let $u=u''$ if $u'-u''\le 1/2,$ or let $u=u''+1$ if $u'-u''>1/2.$ In either case we have $m=u'n$ and $|u-u'|\le 1/2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $r \leqslant \frac{n}{2}$ in the first case. Otherwise, it works. In fact, you can choose any interval for $v$ and expect unique representation as long as the interval has the same length as $[0,n-1]$. You must also change the bound for $v$ to
$$-\frac{n}{2}<v\leqslant\frac{n}{2}$$
As $v \neq -\frac{n}{2}$ in any case.